# How to find a sequence of formatted digits in Apache Nifi using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, csv, apache-nifi

I want to find using Apache Nifi this kind of text in a CSV with lots of text:

**nnnn?nn**

where n is a digit between 0 and 9, and ? is a literal question mark.

A real example is:

**8764?23**

It always has 4 digits before `?` and 2 digits after.

How can this be done?

Comment: _"I want to find"_ How? Using what? Notepad++? A programming language? It's not recommended to use the [regex] tag solely.

Comment: Using NiFI, edited

Comment: Well, have you tried Kamil's answer and it didn't work? If so, please edit your question and explain what you have tried and what it produces compared to your expected output. Here's another very simple solution [`\b\d{4}\?\d{2}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/DzpHok/1).

Comment: @Jesus, what exactly in nifi is not clear? what input do you have and what output required. or question just in regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

Starting off simple:

```
\d{4}\?\d{2}
```

But this would also match `8764?23` within a longer string such as `98764?23` or `8764?234`.

If you need to find exact matches as individual *values* within the CSV, a more complex regular expression is needed:

```
(?:^|,)\s*(\d{4}\?\d{2})\s*(?:,|$)
```

This may look a bit strange at first sight so let's break it down:

- `(?:^|,)` uses the `(something|something else)` syntax to allow a choice of two different things - here it is allowing either the very start of the string `^` or a comma `,`. The `?:` at the start excludes this expression from being included as a capturing group.
- `\s*` allows any amount of whitespace (i.e. zero or more spaces, tabs etc.) to appear before the matched expression.
- `(\d{4}\?\d{2})` specifies exactly 4 digits `\d{4}` followed by a question mark `\?` *(which needs to be escaped to distinguish it from the regex `?` meaning 0 or 1 occurrences)*, followed by 2 more digits `\d{2}`. The surrounding brackets `()` are used to specify this as a capturing group.
- `\s*` allows more whitespace after the matched expression.
- `(?:,|$)` allows either a comma `,` or the end of the string `$` and `?:` excludes this from being a capturing group.

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/X0Ic4v/1

**Usage**

The above can be used with Nifi's [`ExtractText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExtractText/index.html) to get the first capturing group for each match. Since it is only the capturing group that is of interest and not the rest of the match, "Include Capture Group 0" can be set to false. Presumably both "Enable Multiline Mode" and "Enable repeating capture group" should be set to true.

**Further considerations**

The above assumes that `8764?23` appears exactly like that as a value in a CSV string. But maybe you need to allow `"8764?23"`? Or possibly others such as `'8764?23'`, `_8764?23_` or even `ABC8764?23DEF`? There are too many possible variants for here a one size fits all so please reply in the comments to state the requirements if the above doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your regular expression:  `\d\d\d\d\?\d\d` and [tool where you can use it](https://regex101.com/r/jm9qH8/1) (and here more [complicated](https://regex101.com/r/jm9qH8/2) version)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Regex required for your needs.

```
(\d{4}\?\d\d)
```